# Async code working in series but not in parallel

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I have some async code that works when I do everything in series by using await, but when I try to execute the same code in parallel using .then() for a performance increase, I start getting null ref errors.

The usage of puppeteer in the launch method is largely irrelevant, as this part works fine. I've just included the code so that it be seen that I'm using async everywhere that needs it. Although I think the problem is with my usage of async and await, I'm not sure whether I should be returning promises instead of using await or if I should using Promise.All instead?

```
            //results is null
            for (const token of allTokens) {
                let url = "https://bscscan.com/token/" + token.contractAddress;
                this.provider.BscScanService.getTokenDataFromWebsite(url).then((results: ScrapeResults) => {
                    console.log("Scraperesults: ", results);
                    this.provider.TokenHolderCountRepo.insertNewTokenHolderCount({
                        tokenId: token.id,
                        holderCount: results.holderCount,
                        date: Date.now()
                    });
                    this.provider.TokenIconRepo.upsertNewIconSource({
                        tokenId: token.id,
                        iconSrc: results.tokenIconSrc
                    });
                    console.log("Done inserts");
                });
            }

            //Working
            for (const token of allTokens) {
                let url = "https://bscscan.com/token/" + token.contractAddress;
                let results:ScrapeResults = await this.provider.BscScanService.getTokenDataFromWebsite(url);
                console.log("Scraperesults: ", results);
                await this.provider.TokenHolderCountRepo.insertNewTokenHolderCount({
                    tokenId: token.id,
                    holderCount: results.holderCount,
                    date: Date.now()
                });
                await this.provider.TokenIconRepo.upsertNewIconSource({
                    tokenId: token.id,
                    iconSrc: results.tokenIconSrc
                });
                console.log("Done inserts");
            }
```

Other methods

```
public async getTokenDataFromWebsite(url: string): Promise<ScrapeResults>{
        return await this.scrapingService.getTrackerData(url);
    }

public async getTrackerData(url: string): Promise<ScrapeResults> {
        let scrapeResult: ScrapeResults;

        try
        {
            scrapeResult = await this.scraper.launch(url);
        }
        catch(err){
            return null;
        }

        return scrapeResult;
    }

async launch(url: string): Promise<ScrapeResults>{
        console.log("Accessing URL: " + url);
        puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
        console.log("1");
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            //@ts-ignore
            headless: true,
            args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        })
        console.log("2");
        const userAgent = new UserAgent();
        console.log("3");
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        console.log("4");
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.toString());
        await page.waitForSelector('body');
        let pageTitle = await page.title();
        console.log("5");
        console.log("Start eval");
        let holderCount: string[] = await page.$$eval(
            '#ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokenHolders > div.row.align-items-center > div.col-md-8 > div.d-flex.align-items-center > div.mr-3',
            elements => elements.map(element => element.textContent));
        let iconSource: string[] = await page.$$eval('img.u-sm-avatar.mr-2[src]', elements => elements.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')));
        let tokenName: string[] = await page.$$eval('div.media-body > span.text-secondary.small', elements => elements.map(element => element.textContent))
        const images = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.images, e => e.src));
        await browser.close();
        console.log("End eval");

        console.log("Holdercount:", holderCount);
        console.log("iconSource:", iconSource);
        console.log("tokenName:", tokenName);

        return {
            holderCount: this.getHolderCountFromWebsiteString(holderCount[0]),
            tokenIconSrc: iconSource[0],
            tokenName: tokenName[0]
        };
    }
```

Comment: How is `.then` supposed to run things in parallel? `async`/`await` is just syntaxic sugar over `.then`. What you actually need is `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 0):

I think `Promise.all` fits better here. You need to wait for `getTokenDataForWebsite` to finish and then for `upsertNewIconSource` and `insertNewTokenHolderCount` in no particular order, which is exactly what you can achieve with that.

Also, async is not "really" parallel, so I wouldn't rely on what you did for performance increase, you have a single thread that will perform all the same tasks anyway, just in a different and slightly less predictable order.

Try something like:

```js
 for (const token of allTokens) {
                let url = "https://bscscan.com/token/" + token.contractAddress;
                let results:ScrapeResults = await this.provider.BscScanService.getTokenDataFromWebsite(url);
              
                await Promise.all([this.provider.TokenHolderCountRepo.insertNewTokenHolderCount({
                    tokenId: token.id,
                    holderCount: results.holderCount,
                    date: Date.now()
                }), this.provider.TokenIconRepo.upsertNewIconSource({
                    tokenId: token.id,
                    iconSrc: results.tokenIconSrc
                })]);
               
            }
```

Comment: Would you be able to write up a short example of how I'd adapt the for loop to use Promise.all instead?